# Proper scatter of Pthreads

Tags: c, pthreads

I'm trying to get PTHREADS running on each CORE separately.

I have my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>

int LOOP;

pthread_barrier_t barrier;

void *thread(){
    int i=0;
    int count =0;
    pthread_barrier_wait(&barrier);
    for (; i<LOOP; i++)
        count++;
    pthread_barrier_wait(&barrier);

    return NULL;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    int nthreads = atoi(argv[1]);
    int i;
    LOOP = atoi(argv[2]);
    pthread_t threads[nthreads];
    pthread_barrier_init(&barrier, NULL, nthreads);
    for (i=1; i < nthreads; i++)
        pthread_create(&(threads[i]), NULL, thread, NULL);

    thread();
    return 0;
}
```

But when analyzing I'm seeing threads running on the same Core.

I'm using Linux. Is there an environment setting i'm forgetting to set?

Thanks!

Comment: `sched_setaffinity()` on Linux.

Comment: Please note that this qustion is pure C not C++

Comment: What value are you using for `LOOP`?  Then do something a bit more CPU intensive than a simple integer increment.  And you need to return the value computed so the calculation doesn't get optimized away.

Comment: this statement: `void *thread(){` is not the correct prototype/declaration for a posix thread function:  it should be: `void *thread( void* arg){`

Comment: the posted code fails to check `argc` before accessing `argv[]` beyond `argv[0]`.  If the command line does not have the expected parameter, then the code will be access a NULL pointer, so trying to read from address 0, which is undefined behaviour and can/will lead to a seg fault event

Comment: why the 'all caps' on the variable 'LOOP'?  Normally, by convention, 'all caps' is reserved for certain abbreviations and for #define and (sometimes) enum value names

Comment: Hi, thanks for the comments. LOOP is actually a define in the compiler, here i simplified it for easy usage, it's equal to roughly 1 million. I do thank you all for the comments on the code, the object is to scatter Pthreads, so i wrote this code in about 2 minutes then spent a hour checking it. @EOF thanks i'll try that!